# Mutex among processes using semaphores

Tags: c, process, mutex

I have 20 processes of two types (A and B). The A processes have to write on a shared memory, the B processes have to read on that memory when all the writers have written. How can I manage this using semaphore?
How many semaphores should I use?

Comment: Too broad. Usually the mutexes/semaphores are associated with the shared resource regardless of the number of processes accessing it.

Comment: Look into the  [Readers-Writers Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Use condition variable instead, much easy to implement. Use the below example:-
I am implementing it by using 3 threads and not using fork().
I am using 3 mutexs and 3 conditions. With the below example you can synchronized or control execution of any number of threads in C. If you see the first thread here it locked mutex lock1 and waiting on cond1, likewise second thread locked mutex lock2 and waits on condition cond2 and 3rd thread locked mutex lock3 and waits on condition cond3. This is the current situation of all the threads after they are being created and now all the threads are waiting for a signal to execute further on its condition variable. In the main thread (i.e. main function, every program has one main thread, in C/C++ this main thread created automatically by operating system once control pass to the main method by kernal) we are calling pthread_cond_signal(&cond1); once this system call done thread1 who was waiting on cond1 will be release and it will start executing. Once it finished with its task it will call pthread_cond_signal(&cond3); now thread who was waiting on condition cond3 i.e. thread3 will be release and it will start execute and will call pthread_cond_signal(&cond2); which will release the thread who is waiting on condition cond2 i.e. in this case thread2. This is the way we can schedule, synchronize, and prioritize thread in multi-threaded environment. I want you to play around with this example. Here I am controlling 3 threads and in your case you just need to control two threads.

```
pthread_cond_t cond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond2 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond3 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock3 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int TRUE = 1;

void print(char *p)
{
  printf("%s",p);
}

void * threadMethod1(void *arg)
{
  printf("In thread1\n");
  do{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &lock1);
    print("I am thread 1st\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond3);/* Now allow 3rd thread to process */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
  }while(TRUE);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * threadMethod2(void *arg)
{
  printf("In thread2\n");
  do
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock2);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond2, &lock2);
    print("I am thread 2nd\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock2);
  }while(TRUE);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * threadMethod3(void *arg)
{
  printf("In thread3\n");
  do
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock3);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond3, &lock3);
    print("I am thread 3rd\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock3);
  }while(TRUE);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t tid1, tid2, tid3;
  int i = 0;

  printf("Before creating the threads\n");
  if( pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, threadMethod1, NULL) != 0 )
        printf("Failed to create thread1\n");
  if( pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, threadMethod2, NULL) != 0 )
        printf("Failed to create thread2\n");
  if( pthread_create(&tid3, NULL, threadMethod3, NULL) != 0 )
        printf("Failed to create thread3\n");
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);/* Now allow first thread to process first */


  sleep(1);
  TRUE = 0;/* Stop all the thread */
  sleep(3);

 /* this is how we join thread before exit from a system */
  /*  
  pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
  pthread_join(tid2,NULL);
  pthread_join(tid3,NULL);*/

 exit(0);
}
```